# Enable div to scroll by keyboard without clicking

Tags: scroll

I have div element in which I am loading text, usually long text, so the div has scrollbars. I can scroll in this div with mouse, when the cursor is on it, but I cant scroll with page up and down, unless I click inside the div first. So Is there a way to avoid this clicking, to do it from code when the text is loaded?

Comment: can you add sample code, like with jsfiddle, to illustrate? i'd like to help, but i'm unclear on your exact issue.

Comment: Yep I can, hope it'll help a bit http://jsfiddle.net/BQQ8C/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, as you described. I appended an input to the content div, then focus() it, rather than trying to focus the div. So, immediately after pressing load text, you can press pg up/dn to scroll div.

[**HERE IT IS**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQQ8C/28/)

```
 $("div").append('<input type="text" id="focusDiv">');
    /*
 Here I need to have some code which gives "focus to the div, so if I press the load text and then immediately PageDown key, sthedvis scrolls down.

 $("button").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div").html("Very long text...");
    $("div").append('<input type="text" id="focusDiv">');
    $('#focusDiv').focus();
});
```

Comment: I was trying to find some more valid solution, but this isn't so bad and works great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer here worked for me:

[Set keyboard focus to a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754275/set-keyboard-focus-to-a-div)

Basically add a `tabindex` to the div:

```
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="-1">
```

then programmatically set the focus using:
   document.getElementById("mydiv").focus();

From the original post:

> The tabindex value can allow for some interesting behaviour.
>
> - If given a value of "-1", the element can't be tabbed to but focus can
>     be given to the element programmatically (using element.focus()).
> - If given a value of 0, the element can be focused via the keyboard and
>     falls into the tabbing flow of the document.
> - Values greater than 0
>     create a priority level with 1 being the most important.

Comment: Can you include the relevant details from the answer you're referencing here?