# Drop down not getting highlighted when using keyboard tab

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, tabs, accessibility

I am trying to highlight the focus of a drop down (just using keyboard tab) but for some reason the drop down doesn't get highlighted even when its in focus. Can someone help me fixing this issue?

I even tried using the below CSS class but for some reason focus is not working but hovering is working fine as expected..

**CSS:**

```
#selector:focus{ 
      outline: #177f7f dotted medium; 
 }

#selector:hover{ --> works!!!
       outline: #177f7f dotted medium; 
  }

#sortResults:focus{ 
        outline: #177f7f dotted medium; 
 }
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="selector" id="selector" style="float:right;">
<span style="width: 95px; padding:0 1px; padding:1px;" class="perPageDisplay">20 per page</span>
     <select title="sort results" id="sortResults" name="priceDropDown" class="listSort styled_forms perPageSelector" style="opacity:0; width:140px;">
        <option value="20" selected="selected">20 per page</option>  
        <option value="40">40 per page</option>                                              
        <option value="60">60 per page</option>                                              
        <option value="80">80 per page</option>                                              
        <option value="100">100 per page</option>                                                                        
        <option value="120">120 per page</option>                       
     </select>                          
 </div>
```

Comment: Give the element a tabindex attribute.

Comment: What browser are you using? They can give different results for select boxes.

Answer (score 0):

That is because a `div` is not focusable by default. However you make it focusable by giving it a `tabindex="-1"` attribute. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809236/1798215) for a longer explanation.

Comment: Div is not focusable, but a select list is by default.

Comment: That's right. But he applied the `:focus` selector to the `div`, so I assumed, he wants to select this element. Of cource, if he wants the select list to focus, then webfrogs answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the code you're posting is correct. You have `opacity:0;` which doesn't make sense... Beyond that, it's working fine for me. I was able to tab over to the dropdown. Here's a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/vsPW9/)**...