# <legend> won't receive :focus event?

Tags: jquery, html, css, focus, focusin

Here is the HTML:

```
              <fieldset>
                <legend>FieldsetName</legend>
                <div></div>
              </fieldset>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
legend:focus {
  background-color: #ffddbe;
  outline: none; 
}
legend.focusin {
  background-color: #ffddbe;
  outline: none; 
}
```

Clicking on it doesn't do anything.

OK, I thought, I'll go with jQuery.

```
$('legend').focusin( function() {
    $(this).addClass('focusin');
    });

$('legend').focusout( function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focusin');
});
```

It doesn't help either.
However, if $('legend') listens to "click", it does what it is supposed to do. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether it is the correct fix, but adding a tabIndex fixes it

```
<legend tabIndex="1">FieldsetName</legend>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6VmmE/)

Comment: Dang, that was fast AND correct. I still have to wait 11 minutes to accept your answer, though. :)

Comment: @Arun - Can you explain why we give the tabIndex="1" for that legend tag?

Comment: @Sudharsan that makes the legend a [focusable element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754275/set-keyboard-focus-to-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use tabindex="0".

```
<legend tabindex="0">FieldsetName</legend>
```

Here's a breakdown of possible tabindex values and use cases:

- tabindex="0" allows an element to receive focus in the order that it appears in the DOM.
- tabindex="1" (or any number greater than 1) defines an explicit tab order. This is almost always a bad idea.
- tabindex="-1" allows elements besides links and form elements to receive focus programmatically