# How to focus into div after append ajax success response using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax response callback like below.

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "search.php?ajaxrequest=yes",
          data: query_string
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $("#wtb_wm_listing").html(data);
            $("#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner").focus();
  });
```

I'm appending returned data into the div "**wtb_wm_listing**" which i have placed into main div "**wtb_wrapper_middle_inner**"

After appending the data I want to key focus on the main div "**wtb_wrapper_middle_inner**"

But when i try to focus, it is not working for me and as well as when i clicked my mouse into the div and try key down the div page is not scroll by pressing keyboard arrows.

In this case when I'm trying to make **hide()** or **addClass()** on that div its working for me.

Mouse scrolling is working for me by hovering the div.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

**NOTE:**

**When I focus that div when page is load, at that time its working well, But when I append some ajax response data into that div, that time only its not working.**

Comment: You can only focus input elements.

Comment: `contenteditable='true' ` and `:input` are focusable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner` is inside `#wtb_wm_listing` , you are basically removing everything inside `#wtb_wm_listing` to replace with `data`, that is why `#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner` does not exists.

You can try using `append()`

[jQuery append() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

[jQuery html() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)

Comment: That div is there only. But focus only is not working, even `#wtb_wm_listing` is in `#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner` only not like you said. See my question. I'm mentioning the main div is `#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot focus a container/div element. Please read the docs on some use cases here: https://api.jquery.com/focus/ if there is a particular input in that div that you would like to focus you can do that. But you can't focus a div. Though you can add a tabindex to any element. And that can simulate a focus.

Comment: Even that div is focusing when I load that page. But after appending data into that div only its not working.

Comment: How do you know the div is focused when it loads? And how do you know when it loses focus?

Answer (score 0):

As the [jQuery docs say about the focus method](https://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (, , etc.) and links (). In recent
>   browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or
>   by mouse clicks on the element.

[Anyways, you can focus a div by adding a tabindex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809236/1449710) and see if your key scrolling works.

see: http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

> The tabindex value can allow for some interesting behaviour.
>
> - If given a value of "-1", the element can't be tabbed to but focus can
>     be given to the element programmatically (using element.focus()).
> - If given a value of 0, the element can be focused via the keyboard and
>     falls into the tabbing flow of the document.
> - Values greater than 0 create a priority level with 1 being the most important.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works

```js
    window.location.hash = '#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner';
```

```css
#wtb_wrapper_middle_inner{
margin-top:500px;  
height:50px; 
  width:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='wtb_wrapper_middle_inner'></div>
```